# How to prove this approximation for a logarithm?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

I need to prove this approximation, but I am unable to conclude
$$\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \approx \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: I'm confused. how does one prove an approximation ? How would I prove that $5$ is approximately equal to $17$ ?

Comment: What exactly does '$\approx$' mean? How close should LHS and RHS be?

Comment: @mercio I suspect '$LHS \ \approx \ RHS$' is a heuristic for $|LHS - RHS| < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \in (0,1)$

Comment: 8 people think this question is well researched?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing y≈x for small x if y=log(x+1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111041/showing-y%e2%89%88x-for-small-x-if-y-logx1)

Comment: @AlecTeal 9 :( In fact, 3 people think the accepted answer is useful. Is usefulness relative to the reader? I think a necessary condition of usefulness is well-definedness of notation. Oh anyway, it was put on hold as off-topic \m/

Comment: I rarely degree on " off-topic ". To me any math question is on topic. Duplicate or such is more appropriate. How can an answer be off topic and have a few good answers ?

Comment: @mick 2 years later, do you still disagree/do not understand? (Or understand now but later disagree if you didn't understand before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\ln(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}m(\sqrt[m]x-1)$.

By the generalized binomial theorem,

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}m\left(\sqrt[m]{1+\frac1n}-1\right)=\\
\lim_{m\to\infty}m\left(\frac1m\frac1n-\frac{m-1}{2m^2}\frac1{n^2}+\frac{(m-1)(2m-1)}{3!m^3}\frac1{n^3}-\frac{(m-1)(2m-1)(3m-1)}{4!m^4}\frac1{n^4}\cdots\right)\\
=\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}-\frac1{4n^4}\cdots$$

Comment: The first two statements are much more complicated than the original question.

Comment: @Teepeemm: glad to know.

Answer (score 21):

We have $$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\log\left(n+1\right)-\log\left(n\right)=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{t}dt
 $$ then by [first mean value theorem for integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration) we have that exists some $c_{n}\in\left[n,n+1\right]
 $ such that $$=\frac{1}{c_{n}}\left(n+1-n\right)=\frac{1}{c_{n}}\approx\frac{1}{n}.
 $$

Comment: using integral test , wonderful proof

Comment: In what sense do you mean ≈? How do you know OP means the same thing as you?

Comment: @BCLC Normally $\approx$ means approximately. I don't know if you use it with another sense, but I always see it with this meaning. However I think it's quite obvious what I mean in this answer, and in fact OP doesn't ask more clarifications.

Comment: Why the downvote? What's the problem?

Comment: @MarcoCantarini When do you say two numbers are approximately equal? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360393/how-to-prove-this-approximation-for-a-logarithm/1360440?noredirect=1#comment2768067_1360440

Comment: @BCLC I really don't understand your”battle”. If your goal is to show that what OP asked is not precise, well, you're right. But I think that also a mathematician can use a “common sense” to understand a problem. And note that you can find a lot of question in this site with $\approx
 $. So I suggest you to do the same question in every single thread. By the way, what I intend in this situation is that we have an error $$\left|\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{c_{n}}-\frac{1}{n}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}\leq\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$ hence, smaller than $1/n$.

Comment: Marco, maybe I'll flag instead. >:P Also this question was put on hold...due to imprecision?

Comment: @BCLC Yes and because the OP didn't write his attempts to prove that.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini How do you know it is due to that? :P

Comment: @BCLC "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." And this is my last comment.

Answer (score 15):

The Taylor series for the function $\log(1+x)$ about the point $x=0$ is
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$
so when $|x|\ll 1$ we have $\log(1+x)\approx x$. See more at [the Wikipedia article on Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

Comment: In what sense do you mean $\approx$? How do you know OP means the same thing as you?

Answer (score 10):

You may apply the fact that, as $x \to a$, for any differentiable function around $a$, we have

> $$
> \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \to f'(a).
> $$

Then take $f(x)=\log (1+x)$, with $f'(x)=\dfrac1{1+x}$, giving as $x \to 0$,
$$
\frac{\log(1+x)-\log(1+0)}{x-0} \to \frac1{1+0}=1
$$ $$
\frac{\log(1+x)}x \to 1,
$$ that is, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \log\left(1+\frac1n\right) \sim \frac1n.
> $$

Comment: I will review your proof. Thank you Olivier.  =)

Comment: @linuxmint You are welcome!

Comment: Is "~" like the one [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/1/b/91bc6fd1176247d929ddad0e4e420719.png) ?

Comment: @BCLC I meant that the quotient tends to $1$ as the variable tends to $0$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa You mean tends to $\infty$?

Comment: @BCLC I meant the variable $x=\frac1n$, which tends to $0$. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

By definition,

$$e^{\ln(1+1/n)}=1+\frac1n.$$

Then, using the crude approximation* $e^x\approx1+x$,

$$1+\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\approx1+\frac1n.$$

---

*By the definition of $e$ and the binomial theorem,

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1+x+\frac{n-1}{2n}x^2+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^2}x^3\cdots\approx1+x.$$

Using the next term will yield

$$1+\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)+\frac12\ln^2\left(1+\frac1n\right)=1+\frac1n,$$
which can be solved for the logarithm.

$$\left(\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)+1\right)^2=1+\frac2n.$$

A pretty contrived method.

Comment: In what sense do you mean $\approx$? How do you know OP means the same thing as you?

Comment: @BCLC - How do you know we both see the same color red?

Comment: @nbubis We don't, conspiracy keanu :)) To be precise, what I mean to ask is: maybe OP meant $LHS \approx RHS$ as $|LHS - RHS| < \epsilon = 0.5$ while Yves Daoust meant $|LHS - RHS| < \epsilon = 0.0000000000001$? Furthermore, what is the domain? I think Yves Daoust's $e^x \approx 1 + x$ is for values of $x \in (-1,1)$. Consider $e^5$. Unless of course Yves Daoust means something different than me by '$\approx$'.

Comment: @BCLC the notion $\approx$ is perfectly standard for anyone who has ever ventured outside the realm of pure mathematics.

Comment: @nbubis Enlighten me, please?

Comment: I wonder if I could use that crude approximation while building a bridge. It would save time.

Comment: The approximation $e^x\approx1+x$ clearly doesn't hold. One is linear the other is exponential.

Comment: Guys, the context of the question is $x=1/n$, where the exponential behavior has not developed and the goal is precisely to explain the linear approximation!

Comment: @BCLC Generally, $f(x)\approx g(x)$ means that the difference is little o of something as $x$ approaches a limit.  Here, the something is "the smallest order term", and the limit is 0.  So $e^x\approx 1+x$ means that $e^x-1-x\in o(x)$ as $x\to 0$ and $\log(1+\frac{1}{n})\approx\frac{1}{n}$ means that $\log(1+\frac{1}{n})-\frac{1}{n}\in o(n^{-1})$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: An alternative is $f(x)/g(x)\to1$ as $x$ approaches its limit.  The usage should usually be specified by the author, but often isn't.  But it doesn't mean $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for a specific $\epsilon$, unless you're looking at an $\epsilon(x)$ that approaches 0.

Comment: @Teepeemm Are those interpretations of $\approx$ two equivalent (the one involving [little o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation) notation (only knew big O before) and the one involving [asymptotic or whatever you call it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis))?

Comment: They aren't equivalent (for example, $e^x\approx 1+5x$ satisfies the second but not the first).  In the first definition, you could replace $o(x)$ with $o(1)$ to get an equivalent (but weaker) definition.

Comment: @Teepeemm So you disagree with nbubis ('perfectly standard') ?

Comment: @PyRulez How about [finance](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10150262000428375&id=13012333374)?

Comment: The short answer is I up-voted his comment, so yes.  The longer answer is that I think it’s standard enough that the meaning could be inferred from context (especially if that context involves Taylor series).  If the context isn’t Taylor series (for example, yours of $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$), then it may require a definition (but notice that we have a different symbol).  I would also classify myself a pure mathematician, so his comment is vacuously true in my case.

Comment: @Teepeemm: this isn't the place to chat.

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't understand. You disagree yet upvoted?

Comment: @bclc: nor for you.

Answer (score 4):

Use the inequality $e^x\ge x+1$. Substitute in $x=\ln(1+\frac1n)$ and $x=-\ln(1+\frac1n)$ to obtain an upper and lower bound for $\ln(1+\frac1n)$.

Comment: Varying $n$, we get the infinite system of inequalities:$$1>\ln\frac21>\frac12>\ln\frac32>\frac13>\ln\frac43>\dotsb$$